# What server does stackoverflow use?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which tools and technologies build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

I just want to know what web server and what database does the stackoverflow use?

Also, is the stackoverflow Q and A engine an open source or proprietary software?

Comment: sounds like a question for meta.

Comment: The engine is proprietary.